# Check textbox existent in an array or list

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a query of 4 columns, col1 int, col2,3,4 are strings.
I want to put the query in array and check if any values matches `textbox.value`.

```
private void CheckHistory()
    {
        String qry = "Select col1,col2,col3,col4 from Table";
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(qry, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<MyArray>();
                while (reader.Read())
                    list.Add(new MyArray { col1 = reader.GetInt32(0), col2 = reader.GetString(1), col3 = reader.GetString(2), col4 = reader.GetString(3) });
                Array PermuteArray = list.ToArray();                     
                Boolean check = PermuteArray.Contains(textbox.text);
                MessageBox.Show(check.ToString());

                int pos = Array.IndexOf(PermuteArray, textbox.text);
                MessageBox.Show(pos.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I got error at list.add said System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I also got error at PermuteArray.Contains(textbox.text). Said Array doesn't contain method.

How do I resolve the errors?
I just wanna check if textbox value already exists and show a warning msg. Thanks!I'm new to C# and stack please forgive me if my format is not right or tags are not specific.

Comment: Why don't you use `list.Contains(textbox.text)` instead?

Comment: @SiyaZhang Sayyid made a valid point. Why do you convert list to array?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN the signature should be like following:

```
var itemExists = Array.contains(array, item);
```

So in your case the check should be done this way.

```
Boolean check = Array.Contains( PermuteArray,   textbox.text);
```

Anyway, I do see some issue with your current implementation. First of all, you don't need to convert your list to array to find an element. Second, of you can just create an array of string by using String.Join method. Third, the naming of the variables.

Comment: You should elaborate on the "...the naming of the variables." part, as OP might not know what you mean.